# How to uninstall PEAR from one installation of PHP and then install it with another existing PHP installation

Tags: php, linux, pear

I have two installations of php on my server. One version of php is 5.2.0 configured with pear, and the other is 5.2.9 configured `--without-pear`. My server is running Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 9).

I would like to uninstall pear (and also PHPUnit) from php 5.2.0, and then reinstall it as part of the 5.2.9 version of php. The pear installation docs don't really cover this type of a situation, although they do tell Linux users to "consult the documentation for the respective distribution" in the event that they want to install pear with a version of php that was configured `--without-pear`. I am having trouble finding such documentation, and even if I did, I am not sure how to remove the existing pear installation first.

Comment: The only difference between `--pear` and `--without-pear` is the absence of `/usr/share/pear` in the `include_path`.

Comment: Okay, it also defines `PEAR_INSTALL_DIR` and `PEAR_EXTENSION_DIR` constants. But those are soft dependencies within PEAR itself.

Comment: @mario Ok. Any thoughts on how to remove PEAR itself? Is it sufficient to simply delete `/usr/local/bin/pear` and `/usr/local/lib/php/PEAR`? (And also remove `/usr/share/pear` from the `include_path` of the php installation it came with?)

Comment: @mario can you add your comments as an answer?

Comment: @TobyAllen: It's too short of a comment ([one-liner](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)), so unsuitable as answer in my eyes. And OP found a better system solution anyway.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is a partial answer to my own question: After trial and error, I discovered that you can uninstall pear by running this command:

`$ sudo pear uninstall pear`

I would like to see this added to the official pear docs, since they don't mention uninstalling pear at all.

Comment: Thanks! sudo was required for me, without it the uninstall fails.

Comment: This is so stupidly simple, i'm ashamed to mention for how long i've been trying to remove pear.

Comment: It's saying **pear/pear not installed** for me. Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

## Use the Command Help

```
pear help
```

You'll see the uninstall command listed in the output. :)

## Output

```
Commands:
build                  Build an Extension From C Source
bundle                 Unpacks a Pecl Package
channel-add            Add a Channel
...
uninstall              Un-install Package
...
```

Comment: As embarrassingly obvious at that may seem, the description for the uninstall command in the help menu says, "Un-install Package"; I wasn't thinking of pear itself as a package, only the pear packages. It took some guesswork for me to realize I could just run `pear uninstall pear` and this simple command (which is not as obvious as it seems) should be added to the official documentation.